# What is a good use-case for reading a HttpWebRequest's response stream asynchronously?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I have this code that uses a lot of `HttpWebRequest` in parallel. It currently does that synchronously, but I'm changing that to asynchronous using `BeginGetResponse` in order to increase performances.

Now I can send the query asynchronously, but still read the response stream synchronously. is it completely stupid to mix both modes? Are there advantages of reading the stream asynchronously too (like taking less time) ?

Comment: Silverlight/WinRT needs it to be async.

Comment: I'm not doing Silverlight nor WinRT, so not relevant in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it completely stupid to mix both modes?

Not at all. It depends on the response.

> Are there advantages of reading the stream asynchronously too (like taking less time) ?

If the server is streaming the response and it takes appreciable time between packets, then it may help to read the response stream asynchronously too.

If the server just sends the response in one chunk, you have to decide whether it is worth the slight extra effort and complexity to implement asynchronous reading.

---

As a rule of thumb, the most important part to run asynchronously is, as you say, `BeginGetResponse`. Otherwise you are always using a thread to wait for the server to generate the response.